# How to pump same amount of paste every time?

Tags: sauce, measurements, mixing, hot-sauce

I am not sure if I am on the right site for this, but here it goes. I have a friend, named Jason, who makes a hot sauce for a company he runs. It is very pasty (made of pepper flakes in an oil).

The problem is, when Jason makes a batch, he's got to continually stir up the batch while trying to pour an equal (and evenly distributed) amount of the paste into the bottles.

He wants a system that makes it easy and predictable to do this faster. Ideally, he would make the paste, put it in something that keeps it stirred so the flakes don't settle, and from there fill each bottle with the same amount of paste.

What kind of contraption would do this?

Comment: I think you are looking for something along the lines of a mixer/dispenser. See this link: http://www.directindustry.com/cat/mixing-dosing/mixer-dispensers-powders-granulates-BG-1049.html. Good luck!

Comment: What sort of scale are we talking about here?  My first thought was a squeeze bottle that could be easily capped and shaken, then just fill the bottles to a known line, but for large bottles that might be more effort than it's worth ... or if you're dealing with many 100s of bottles at a time.

Comment: Hey, Joe! He is dealing with about 12 pints at a time.

Answer (score 4):

This thought came to me, and is so different from my first answer I don't think it makes a good edit to that...

If the product is really

> made of pepper flakes in an oil

rather than mix a batch at all, measure out a bottle's worth of each, funnel in the flakes, pour in the oil (and seal/heat-process if that's normally done.) Might need some vibration/shaking, but two easily dispensed components mixed in the bottle might be a lot easier than getting the mixture nicely dispensed.

Answer (score 1):

When I consider pumping pasty things with flakes in them and dispensing a known amount, a peristaltic pump is what comes to mind. Some pump controllers have built in ability to be calibrated and dispense a known volume automagically.

Keeping the product mixed before the pump is a different matter. I guess there are some super-cheap (no idea how effective) pot-stirrers now, or there are more expensive ones. Here's a cheap one, I guess it stands in the pot and wiggles its "feet."

[image: Cheap Pot Stirrer]

Unless there's significant budget the peristaltic pump (particularly one with dispensing ability) may be too expensive.

Comment: Actually, with the pot stirrer, you might be able to put the pot up high, with a tube in it so that you can create a siphon.

Comment: might also be able to drill a 5 gallon bucket and put a spigot on it.

Comment: Neither seems all that compatible with a product that's described as being a "paste." I suppose dumping it into a pastry bag and piping it might work, if you can stand the inevitable losses to stuff that goes into the bag and not out again.

Comment: Yeah, there's that ... but then i thought about it -- just how thick of a paste is it, if it's going into bottles?  I guess it could be like ketchup, where it needs some extra effort to get it out, but if it were really thick, it'd be going into jars so you could scoop it out, not pour it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a large graduated syringe. such as

[image]

if you can find one very large then you will not have to fill it as often. You cut the tip to optimize flow.  The graduation marks will aid in dispensing the proper amount each time.

The medical frock is optional.